# Can't get smoke from Quick Object - Smoke Setting

Tags: smoke-simulation

Disclaimer : I started learning blender 3 days back.

I am trying to replicate a tutorial of creating smoke in blender, but I don't get any effect even after following the steps.

1. In the default sphere, I add Quick Object -> Quick Smoke.
   When I play a simulation, nothing happens whereas in many videos I saw just after adding the smoke box(if that's what it's called), they can see the box turning into smoke.

Version: 2.8
Attached Snaps of settings.

[image: The basic stuff]

[image: Settings(Physics)]

[image: Physics again]

Answer (score 0):

Is your outer "smoke box" being used as domain and is "adaptive domain" checked? Make sure the smoke has room to move.

[image]

From this tutorial, which might help: 
https://youtu.be/6DjGpppAUfI?t=147

Comment: Thanks for the response mig, I was not baking it before